Did Stack Exchange and Facebook discuss any ownership rights for the site meta.stackexchange.com and meta.com?
I am curious what the legal ownership is around websites such as meta.stackexchange.com and meta.com considering they are both titled the same. I understand the legal definition of a word is not something that can be held and it depends on the context.
This is something I would like to use as an example when talking about Intellectual Property Portfolios and trademark/patent law with Information Technology students. For example when establishing a new website, how would a person go about researching if one is already an existing trademark or if it would be possible to have that domain? Obviously you could not take the same exact site, but could facebook.stackexchange.com exist?
Is there any publicly available filing that I could use to guide this discussion? Do any news articles exist in Wired or online blog posts related to this topic? The only news I can find related to this type of thing I can understand is with the Roller Derby and Baseball teams in Cleveland (https://www.wkyc.com/article/sports/mlb/cleveland-guardians/cleveland-guardians-baseball-club-amicable-resolution-lawsuit-roller-derby-team/95-fb260fa2-c3c6-4444-be14-ecba2ae89e4e).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Mark renamed to Meta way after meta.stackexchange.com was established. If anything, Mark has to pay SE for having to deal with the support tickets for his site.

Stack Exchange has no claim on the word "meta". They do have a claim on meta.stackexchange.com. Facebook has no claim on the stackexchange.com domain. To make that claim would be silly - anybody can create any subdomain on their site. That doesn't automatically give somebody else claim over it. Moreover, nobody owns "words". At best there is a trademark for something but the trademark is registered for a given context. Classic example is Apple Computers and the music studio that produced the Beatles: Apple Records.

@VLAZ but we were first with using Meta! Right? ... yes? Please?

@rene I think whoever create <meta> tags in HTML was before us. Therefore, SE has to pay W3C. /s

While the question might be interesting I doubt it is a good fit to be discussed here. First  of all I doubt anyone in the know would be allowed to comment on the topic and secondly you seem to be asking us to find external resources for you. That is off-topic on most sites and so it is on MSE. I don't think in its current state this question has lasting value for future visitors of MSE.

In 2001 the first forum I was actively involved in (later, in 2003) already had a "Meta Board" sub-forum, and I doubt they were the first.

I see, the wording was poor - I am not a lawyer. I do appreciate the response that nobody owns "words" as this is an important point to stress @VLAZ also the topic of a subdomain and its ownership is worth noting. I appreciate the responses and also understand if another site might be better such as https://law.stackexchange.com/

This question was asked a few years ago here on MSE like this (likely deleted now).

The issue here isn't the "wording" - the issue is that there is no coherent basis for asking about this. It makes as much sense as wondering whether grocery stores have had to negotiate with Apple Computer, Inc. before selling apples.

@KarlKnechtel it is not, and also that is called a false equivalence

The 'concept' of meta sites on the network dates back to at least 2009. Meta platforms inc renamed itself in 2021.
Considering they named themselves after the metaverse - a concept that first originated in the 1992 science fiction novel Snow Crash, I really don't think an attempt to claim the meta name as their sole property has any grounds. IANAL, but really considering how amazingly well their attempts at a metaverse has gone, maybe the rename was a little premature.
Meanwhile we're talking about the network, and sites on our meta sites. Its not as busy as it used to be, but the meta sites still serve their purpose.

This just in - ancient Greeks want back pay from anybody using their word "meta".

Written in on a pottery shard?
